# Java binary file format is not reducing file size very much

Tags: java, csv, binary, byte

I have multiple large csv files (~100MB each) which, I thought I would convert to binary format to save disk space. I am reading csv file line by line and converting each line from string to an array of bytes and saving that array to file in the manner below:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);   
    String line;
    byte[] storeLine;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        storeLine = line.getBytes();
        out.write(storeLine);
        out.flush();
    }
    out.close();
```

When I run this, I find that the newly constructed binary file is not much smaller than the csv file. Is this normal when writing Strings to binary or is there something I could do to optimize this?

Ex: csv file - 99851Kb
    binary file - 99646Kb

Comment: A text file _is_ an array of bytes. The reduced size probably comes from the missing linebreaks.

Comment: @tkausl so you are saying that there is no way of reducing a csv file size?

Comment: You can compress it with gzip.